# Hidden form field not working in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angularjs-scope, hidden-field

Here is my html form in laravel application which has hidden fields, these hidden values need to send to the angular js controller.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden"  value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input name="user_id" type="hidden"  value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
    <input name="post_id"  type="hidden" value="<% post.id %>" >
    <input name="published_at" type="hidden" value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d') }}">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="comment"  ng-model="contentField" type="text" >
    <button type="submit" ng-click="addComment()">comment</button>
</form>
```

My Angular Controller is as follows

```
 $scope.addComment = function(){
     var comment = {
       user_id: $scope.user_id,
       content: $scope.contentField,
       post_id: $scope.post_id,
       published_at: $scope.published_at
 };
```

I am only getting the value of contentField in the controller, Please Help me to solve this problem !

Comment: I would drop the use of type="hidden" and value=".." in favor of the angular directives ng-hide="true" and ng-model="...".  Setting value equal to something does not bind it to the model in angular.  Also, put your comment variable on $scope as $scope.comment and bind directly to it like ng-model="comment.user_id"

Comment: There is any other method to send hidden form  values without using ng-model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the `ng-model` tags on your hidden imports. Because of that angular does not know how or where to bind the hidden input values to the `$scope`. Adding those tags to all of the hidden inputs should fix your issue of them not being found on the `$scope`.

Comment: I had tried ng-model before.Without using hidden field it's working fine But using hidden field value is not sent, Here actual Problem is i have to send hidden values to the angular's function using form.

Comment: If you use ng-hide rather than type="hidden" you will be able to interact with the model as necessary.

Comment: Now it's Working, But when pushing values using callback method only comment pushed to the array. I need to push userName and userImage to the array How can i push them too. any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

We can simply try like this:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="post_id" ng-init="post_id=<% post.id %>"/>
```

OR

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="post_id" value="{{post_id}}" ng-init="post_id=<% post.id %>"/>
```

OR

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="post_id" value="<% post.id %>" ng-init="post_id=<% post.id %>"/>
```

Note: here `ng-init` is doing the trick binding whatever from another model or object or direct value :)